# Cmp instruction mismatch

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I have to write a function in assembly to complete the following c code.

```
int main(){

int hist[26]={0};
int i;

charHistogram("This is a string", hist);

for (i=0; i<26; i++ )
printf("%c:%d ", i+’a’, hist[i] );
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

And this is the assembly code I wrote:

```
_charHistogram:

push %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
subl $0x10,%esp
movl $0x0,-0x4(%ebp) 
movl $0x41,-0x8(%ebp)

condFor1:

movl  -0x4(%ebp),%edx
movl  0X8(%ebp),%eax
cmp  (%eax,%edx,1), $0
je  exit

condFor2:

cmpl $0x5a,-0x8(%ebp)
jg   condFor1

if1:

movl -0x8(%ebp), %ecx
cmp (%eax,%edx,1), %ecx
jne if2 
subl $0x41,%ecx
movl 0xc(%ebp), %ebx
add $0x1, (%ebx,%ecx,4)
add 0x20,%ecx
inc %ecx
inc %edx
jmp condFor1

if2:

add 0x20,%ecx
cmp (%eax,%edx,2), %ecx
jne condFor1
subl $0x41,ecx
movl 0xc(%ebp), %ebx
add $0x1, (%ebx,%ecx,4)
add 0x20,%ecx
inc %ecx
inc %edx
jmp condFor1

exit:

leave
ret
```

Basically the function written in assembly has to count the number of occurences of a letter on a given string and store it at the int array *hist*. So I thought it could compare each char value to its ascii value starting at 65 to 90 and from 97 to 122. But when I begin to compile the assembly it keeps getting the error  "operand size mismatch for 'cmp'" for the instruction `cmp (%eax,%edx,1), $0`. 
Can you help me out?

Comment: for readability, please indent the C source code.  suggest 4 spaces after an opening brace '{' and un-indent before a closing brace '}'

Comment: I think the entry point needs to be declared .global so it can be called

Answer (score 3):

```
cmp  (%eax,%edx,1), $0
```

You need to reverse the operands.

```
cmp  $0, (%eax,%edx,1)
```

Did you notice that you have programmed endless loops?
You setup a variable with `movl $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)` but you are forgetting to change its value throughout the code!

Since your input string is ASCIIZ shouldn't you compare with CL in stead of comparing with ECX?

Comment: yeah you´re right. it worked. Yes i've already changed the loops, thanks for the heads up. Theres a problem if i change de %ecx to %cl the i can't get the position of the int array that i get using add $0x1, (%ebx,%ecx,4). i says %cl is not valid base/index

Comment: The advice given to change %ecx into %cl only pertains to both compare instructions! `cmp (%eax,%edx,1), %cl` and `cmp (%eax,%edx,2), %cl` All other uses of %ecx can savely remain.